# ArcMap keeps loading old CSV file after I've updated it

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, arccatalog

I have a CSV I'd like to join to a shapefile. I brought the CSV into ArcMap, realized it had an error, fixed it and saved the file with the same name. I removed the CSV from my map document, refreshed the CSV's enclosing folder, and brought the CSV into the map document again. It is still the old CSV, with error. I verified that I had saved it correctly. I had. I closed Excel, and reopened the CSV: still correct. I 'reloaded' the CSV in ArcMap's table of contents. Still the old version.

I know I can resave the CSV with a new name to get around this issue but I want to figure it out. What am I doing wrong? How can I get ArcMap to recognize the updated CSV file?

Answer (score 5):

Go into Windows File Explorer and look at the folder where your CSV is saved.  There is likely an associated XML file that was created when you first added it to ArcMap - they create this supplemental file to manage table headers etc.  If you remove the CSV from your table of contents, delete the XML and reload, it should update.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue has been fixed in ArcGIS Pro. Here is a good writeup for working with CSVs in ArcGIS Pro. [Work with Microsoft Excel and CSV files in ArcGIS Pro](https://esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/natural-resources/working-with-excel-files-in-arcgis-pro/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).