# Ask ArcMap to recognize updated CSV file content

Tags: arcmap, csv, table, update

I have a CSV file that I am updating outside of ArcMap (v10.4.1).

How can I get ArcMap to see the revised content instead of the old content?

ArcMap does not automatically see the updated version.

My current solution is to exit ArcMap and start a new session, which is time consuming.

I have already tried:

- removing the CSV from the Table of Contents and reintroducing using drag-and-drop from the Arc Catalog pane,
- removing from TOC, then reintroducing using the "Add Data" tool ("Standard" toolbar).
- starting a new MXD using the "New" tool ("Standard" toolbar).
- converting to DBF by right-clicking on the CSV in the Arc Catalog pane.

*This problem seems  to be non-reproducible.* I am not able to reproduce minutes after the original post.

I am running on a network which has noticible interruptions a few times a day, typically. I wonder if ArcMap will uses a cached copy if it cannot reload from the network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArcMap keeps loading old CSV file after I've updated it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298862/arcmap-keeps-loading-old-csv-file-after-ive-updated-it)

Comment: @Hornbydd the "problem" seems not to be reproducible (recently, the CSV _with updates_ is seen after closing in the Table pane, then reopening). Also, there is no XML file (and I even checked for hidden files), so no, that [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298862/arcmap-keeps-loading-old-csv-file-after-ive-updated-it) does not answer the question.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the folder holding the csv (R click -> Refresh in Catalog pane) before you drag-and-drop it back in? That might be something to try if it happens again.